# Is there an easy way to add an empty border around the entire diagram in Dia?

Tags: dia

I'm generating a png, and the edges of the images are right alongside the outlying objects in the diagram. I'd like to add a little whitespace around the diagram. I've done it so far by adding white lines on two of the sides, but I was hoping there is a way to just specify a certain amount of padding either all the way around or per side. I don't see the setting myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the `Standard-Box` around your diagram and then just set its `Draw Background` property to `No`. Here you can layer you diagram and border box like this `Layers -> Add Layer...`, name the layer and now you can draw `Standard-Box` there.

**Tip:** If you don't see `Layer Bar` then just go to `View->Show Layers`.